# Unable to update state (collection of objects with keys and values) of a react component

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-redux

I am uploading multiple videos on AWS S3.

```js
const [files, setFiles] = useState(
[
{
        fileData: File,
        canceled: false,
        progress: 0,
        fileName: "fileName1.mp4",
},
{
        fileData: File,
        canceled: false,
        progress: 0,
        fileName: "fileName2.mp4",
},
]
)
```

in S3 upload, we can track the progress of upload on the trigger of a callback. So i want to update my state (files) whenever there is an update of progress.

I am using a function to update the state.

```js
const updateProgress = (fileName, progress) => {

//fileName - the file whose progress property we need to update,
// progress- the progress in number
    
}
```

The update progress is called very rapidly (even more rapid, when number of videos are more), and when I am updating the progress of a file, the other files progress get assigned as zero.

I also tried redux, but same results.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following to update the progress of particular file only.

```js
const updateProgress = (fileName, progress) => {

    //fileName - the file whose progress property we need to update,
    // progress- the progress in number

    let newArr = [...files]; // copying the old datas array
    const fileIndex = newArr.findIndex(file => file.fileName === fileName);
    newArr[fileIndex].progress = progress;
    setFiles(newArr);
}
```

Comment: I tried doing what exactly you said, but it's not updating properly.

Progress is getting a value of 100, after saving.

screenshot: http://prntscr.com/ryckun

also i did below,

    let newArr = [...files];
    const fileIndex = newArr.findIndex((file) => file.fileName === fileName);
    newArr[fileIndex] = {...newArr[fileIndex], progress:progress};
    console.log(fileName,progress,newArr);

in this case, when updating one record, after saving it, the progress of other records are getting saved as 0.

Comment: have you tried using the throttle feature of  developer tools to debug this issue which is to limit the internet speed?

Comment: Please check my comment above. or refer this screenshot https://prnt.sc/rycp07

Comment: debugger tool I am using now, but tried earlier all combinations. Still the same result.